MySQL: 'Order by' clause not doing anything?
I have the following sql code written:
SELECT Country, ROUND(SUM(Consumption), 2) AS 'Total Consumption'
FROM alcohol
GROUP BY Country
ORDER BY 'Total Consumption' DESC;

When I run this code, the output is not sorted by 'Total Consumption' at all; it only returns the data sorted in the original order (alphabetically by Country). Out of curiosity, I tried sorting it in ASC order instead of DESC (though DESC is what I want), and got the same result.
My apologies if I'm just missing something obvious, since I'm a relative beginner lol.
When I run the prior code, I expect it to return all of the countries and the 'Total Consumption' values, sorted with the highest 'Total Consumption' at the top and descending. What I get is all of the countries and their 'Total Consumption' values, sorted by 'Country' alphabetically from A to Z (which is how the original dataset is sorted).

This works in sql server. MySQL must not recognize the alias. Use the full fuction.

Use backticks, not single quotes.

An alias with a space is part of the problem here (ie, don't use single quotes but rather backticks as Barmar mentioned) . Easier to just say order by 2 desc or even change your alias to Total_Consumption then no ticks or quotes are needed.

@adveach Doesn't SQL-Server use square brackets?

@Barmar Yes it does, although single quotes also works some of the time if you use the deprecated setting SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;

Thanks very much to the comments for answering my question; turns out MySQL doesn't recognize the alias and I just had to order by the original function. That works perfectly. Thanks again everyone!

You didn't give it an alias to use. You gave it a string literal.

As I said above, if you simply wrapped the alias in backticks instead of single quotes, it would have worked fine.
